# The motion of the projectile

Tags: algebra-precalculus, classical-mechanics

I've got the following
$$h(t) = -\frac{1}{2} gt^2 + Vt + h'$$
where $h'$ and $V$ are the initial height and velocity of the object, respectively. 
Suppose a person standing at the top of the tower of pisa ($176$ft high) throws a ball directly upward with an initial speed of $96$ft/s. 
Find the ball's height, its velocity and acceleration at time.

Comment: You should tell us how you approached the problem and show us your attempt!

Comment: Hint: what forces are acting on the ball? Do you know the relationship between position, velocity and acceleration?

Comment: @Euler_Salter: I'm not sure the OP needs all that.  The formula already incorporates all that information.  They have gravity, the initial height, and the velocity; they just need to know to plug them into the parameters of the formula.

Comment: OP: This is a simple plug-in.  Everything is a known parameter except the variable $t$.  Also, your post is missing the end: at time $t = $ what? This lack of effort is typically frowned upon here.

Comment: @BrianTung true, although maybe knowing that could help him solve all these kind of problems

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with discrete mathematics.

Comment: @BrianTung I think he is looking for velocity and acceleration as functions of times

Comment: @Euler_Salter: That's my guess, too, but I prefer OP to lay that out.

Comment: It is not a site that does homework for you. It is for those who try at least one time the question and show their attempt here with their question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can solve this problem:

- For the height, just plug in whatever $t$ is into the formula for $h(t)$.
- For the velocity, because of gravity, the velocity decreases by $g$ for every second, so it decreases by $gt$ for every $t$ seconds. Thus, we get $v(t)=V-gt$, so to get the velocity, just plug in whatever $t$ is into that formula.
- The acceleration is $a(t)=-g$ regardless of time as that is the acceleration due to gravity.